# Does the compactness definition hold under arbitrary unions?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

A set in the real line is compact iff every open covering (finite or infinite) has a finite subcovering. In many texts the infinite covering is assumed to be union of countably many open sets (i.e. open intervals) in the real line. I guess in the real line countable unions suffice since the rational numbers are dense.

Am wondering, does the compactness definition generalize to arbitrary unions of other topological spaces ? i.e. in general, a set in a topological space is compact iff for any arbitrary open covering (which for instance can be an uncountable union of open sets) there is a finite subcovering ... is there an example of this ,?

Comment: These spaces are called [Lindelof spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20Lindel%C3%B6f%20space,existence%20of%20a%20finite%20subcover.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of compactness states that a space $X$ is compact if for any open cover $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $X$ (where $I$ is any set at all), there is a finite subcover.

The real question is: what is the relationship of a basis with compactness?

Suppose $\{B_j\}_{j \in J}$ is a basis for $S$. Suppose that any subcover of $\{B_j\}_{j \in J}$ has a finite subcover.

Now consider an arbitrary open cover $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ of $S$. Define $K \subseteq J$ by $K = \{j \in J \mid \exists i \in I (B_j \subseteq U_i)\}$.

Because $\{B_j\}_{j \in J}$ is a basis, $\{B_k\}_{k \in K}$ must be an open cover of $U_i$ for all $i \in I$. Therefore, $\{B_k\}_{k \in K}$ has a finite subcover $\{B_{k_n}\}_{n = 1, 2, ..., m}$.

For each $n$ between $1$ and $m$, take some $i_n$ such that $B_{k_n} \subseteq U_{i_n}$. Then we see that $\{U_{i_n}\}_{n = 1, 2, ..., m}$ is a finite subcover of $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$.

Thus, we see that $S$ is compact.

This means that when one is proving that a topological set is compact, it suffices to consider subcovers of a given basis. In particular, $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a countable basis, and hence so do all its subspaces. So when proving that a space with a countable basis is compact, it suffices to consider subcovers of that basis - that is, to consider only a certain class of countable covers.

Comment: In particular, all second countable spaces are Lindelof, which is the property required to only consider countable covers in the proof of compactness.